# Heroku error in server

Tags: php, heroku

I tried to make a server (site) with help Open Tok and Heroku. I made from this https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php and made in order. After this I changed run-demo and I wrote api key and secret in there. I can to launch and I can to see api key, sessionId, and token. But I cannot to launch my site from Heroku. I tried several different variant but I could not to make this. And when I try to connect with my site and I get error

> "The page you are looking for could not be found. Check the address
>   bar to ensure your URL is spelled correctly. If all else fails, you
>   can visit our home page at the link below."

How can I fix it?